# WP order post by publish date

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have been trying for days to sort the posts that will be shown in the homepage of a template in Wordpress based on their publication date. In particular I have tried to sort the array that contains the post_id with different functions (array_multisort, ksort, usort etc.) but without getting to the mentioned purpose. Could you help me overcome that difficulty? Here is the code of the template parts:

```
<?php
$date_publish = new DateTime($post->post_date);
$manual_articles = dsi_get_option("manual_articles", "homepage");
if(is_array($manual_articles) && count($manual_articles)){
?>

    <section class="section bg-white py-2 py-lg-3 py-xl-5">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="title-section pb-4">
            <h2 class="h2"><?php _e("News"); ?></h2>
        </div><!-- /title-section -->
        <div class="row variable-gutters">
                <?php
                foreach ( $manual_articles as $idpost ) {
                    if(++$i > 3) break; // 3 post max
                    $post = get_post($idpost); 
//                  echo strtotime($post->post_date);
                    if($post->post_type != "event") {
                        ?>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 mb-4">
                            <?php
                                get_template_part("template-parts/single/card-vertical-thumb", $post->post_type);
                            ?>
                        </div>
                        <?php
                    }
                }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    </section>
```

Sort an array with a different function with no result

Comment: Hi, please refer to [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/115152/last-post-ordered-by-publish-date-using-wp-query-on-front-page) answer in stack exchange for a similar question

Comment: why you need dsi_get_option to call the posts? also you can simply create the query to get posts  

$query = new WP_Query(array(
    'cat' => 4,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'orderby' => 'publish_date',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'paged' => $page,
    'posts_per_page' => $postsPerPage));